# AngularJS: locationChange load route after preventDefault

Tags: angularjs, preventdefault

I do the following in my AppController:

```
app.controller('AppController',function($scope,$translate,$http,$location){
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e, next, current) {
        if (checkLogin() === false) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
});
```

checkLogin returns true if the User-Session is valid and false if not. The preventDefault works fine, and the route is loaded if checkLogin is true.

But it does not refer to "/login", if checkLogin is false.

Any ideas why or what i am doing wrong?

Thanks so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "...but it does not refer to `/login`"?

Comment: it does not change the route to "/login" ..

Comment: Can you give more information - could you give details about `checkLogin()` - I don't think this code is necessary, but can you try enclosing the `$location.path()` code inside `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: So far the checkLogin() function always returns false, so e.preventDefault(); $location.path('/login'); should always be executed. e.preventDefault works fine, but the route change to "/login" does not happen.